# Backbone.js - Filter a Collection based on an Array containing multiple keywords

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm using `Backbone.js/Underscore.js` to render a `HTML` table which filters as you type into a textbox. In this case it's a basic telephone directory.
The content for the table comes from a Collection populated by a JSON file.
A basic example of the JSON file is below:

```
[{
    "Name":"Sales and Services",
    "Department":"Small Business",
    "Extension":"45446",
},
{
    "Name":"Technical Support",
    "Department":"Small Business",
    "Extension":"18800",
},
{
    "Name":"Research and Development",
    "Department":"Mid Market",
    "Extension":"75752",
}]
```

I convert the text box value to lower case and then pass it's value along with the Collection to this function, I then assign the returned value to a new Collection and use that to re-render the page.

```
filterTable = function(collection, filterValue) {
    var filteredCollection;
    if (filterValue === "") {
        return collection.toJSON();
    }
    return filteredCollection = collection.filter(function(data) {
        return _.some(_.values(data.toJSON()), function(value) {
            value = (!isNaN(value) ? value.toString() : value.toLowerCase());
            return value.indexOf(filterValue) >= 0;
        });
    });
};
```

The trouble is that the function is literal. To find the "Sales and Services" department from my example I'd have to type exactly that, or maybe just "Sales" or "Services". I couldn't type "sal serv" and still find it which is what I want to be able to do.

I've already written some javascript that seems pretty reliable at dividing up the text into an array of Words (now updated to code in use).

```
toWords = function(text) {
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    text = text.replace(/[^A-Za-z_0-9@.]/g, ' ');
    text = text.replace(/[\s]+/g, ' ').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
    text = text.split(new RegExp("\\s+"));
    var newsplit = [];
    for (var index in text) {
        if (text[index]) {
            newsplit.push(text[index]);
        };
    };
    text = newsplit;
    return text;
};
```

I want to loop through each word in the "split" array and check to see if each word exists in one of the key/values. As long as all words exist then it would pass the truth iterator and get added to the Collection and rendered in the table.

So in my example if I typed "sal serv" it would find that both of those strings exist within the Name of the first item and it would be returned.
However if I typed "sales business" this would not be returned as although both the values do appear in that item, the same two words do not exist in the Name section.

I'm just not sure how to write this in Backbone/Underscore, or even if this is the best way to do it. I looked at the documentation and wasn't sure what function would be easiest.

I hope this makes sense. I'm a little new to `Javascript` and I realise I've dived into the deep-end but learning is the fun part ;-)
I can provide more code or maybe a JSFiddle if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using underscore's `any` and `all` make this relatively easy. Here's the gist of it:

```
  var toWords = function(text) {
    //Do any fancy cleanup and split to words
    //I'm just doing a simple split by spaces.
    return text.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);
  };

  var partialMatch = function(original, fragment) {   
    //get the words of each input string
    var origWords = toWords(original + ""), //force to string
        fragWords = toWords(fragment);

    //if all words in the fragment match any of the original words, 
    //returns true, otherwise false
    return _.all(fragWords, function(frag) {
      return _.any(origWords, function(orig) {
        return orig && orig.indexOf(frag) >= 0;
      });
    });
  };

  //here's your original filterTable function slightly simplified
  var filterTable = function(collection, filterValue) {
      if (filterValue === "") {
          return collection.toJSON();
      }
      return collection.filter(function(data) {
          return _.some(_.values(data.toJSON()), function(value) {
              return partialMatch(value, filterValue);
          });
      });
  };
```

**Note:** This method is computationally pretty inefficient, as it involves first looping over all the items in the collection, then all the fields of each item, then all words in that item value. In addition there are a few nested functions declared inside loops, so the memory footprint is not optimal. If you have a small set of data, that should be OK, but if needed, there's a number of optimizations that can be done. I might come back later and edit this a bit, if I have time.

/code samples not tested

Comment: Thanks! That's given me a very good starting point. Forgive my stupidity but I can't see the documentation on the .any and .all functions, are they now called .every and .some?

Comment: @Equalsk, Yes, they are the same as every and some. Both names work, but for some reason I prefer some of the aliases to the primary names.

Comment: This worked straight out of the box! Thanks @fencliff. The collection will only have upto 2000 records each with 15 values, do you think the code would need optimizing at all? I don't have the completed JSON data to test with yet so I can't tell how it performs. Now that I understand the concept I can always tweak it myself.

Comment: With `(2000 * 15 = 30000)` comparable values I would definitely optimize. I might get back to this when I have time, since I think partially searchable Backbone collection would be a cool thing to have in my toolbelt, but probably not today.

Comment: No problem, your help so far has been far more than I expected! I'll take a look at this myself and if I come up with anything I'll be sure to edit my answer :-)